# React-Day-Picker DayPicker Component Not Closing When Clicking Outside Calendar

Tags: reactjs, calendar, react-day-picker

I am having an issue utilizing the `DayPicker` api for use of the pop-up calendar. I need to close/hide when I click outside the calendar. I want to work like the `DayPickerInput` component work but with our the textbox input.  I **ONLY** need the popup calendar. Using `onBlur` only partially works because if I click a week, it does not immediately recognize the focus the calendar container.  I am really struggling with this and I am sure there is a simple solution.

Here is code snippet:

```
    <div className={calendarPopOut} onBlur={handleClickOutside}>
      <DayPicker
         disabledDays={currentCalendarWeek}
         className={dayPicker}
         showOutsideDays
         month={currentSelectedMonth}
         toMonth={currentMonth}
         weekdayElement={<ThreeCharacterAbv />}
         onDayClick={handleChange}
         onBlur={handleClickOutside}
       />
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ref to the datepicker container and create a event listener on document click and close the datepicker.

```
const datePickerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

// Add event listener to close the date picker when clicked outside
useEffect(() => {
  const handleClickOutside = (event: MouseEvent) => {
      // Close the date picker only when clicked outside
      if (
        datePickerRef.current &&
        event.target instanceof Node &&
        !datePickerRef.current.contains(event.target)
      ) {
        handleCloseDayPicker();
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
    };
}, [handleCloseDayPicker]);


<div className={calendarPopOut} ref={datePickerRef}>
    <DayPicker
       disabledDays={currentCalendarWeek}
       className={dayPicker}
       showOutsideDays
       month={currentSelectedMonth}
       toMonth={currentMonth}
       weekdayElement={<ThreeCharacterAbv />}
       onDayClick={handleChange}
       onBlur={handleCloseDayPicker}
     />
 </div>
```

I have specified the types you can remove them if your not using typescript.
Hope this helps!